# Egit vs Git showing changes on multiple branches?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

We've recently moved to Git and are using Egit in Eclipse Juno and have noticed a problem with branch switching. The sequence is:

1. In BranchA make a change
2. Do not stage or commit change
3. Switch to BranchB

   - Problem:

     - No error to recommend stash/abandon/commit changes
     - BranchA change shows up in BranchB
4. Make change in BranchB
5. Do not stage or commit change
6. Switch to BranchA

   - Problem:

     - No error to recommend stash/abandon/commit changes
     - BranchB change shows up in BranchA

This seems very counter-intuitive as it appears Egit it mixing uncommitted changes among branches? I have to be doing something wrong as this couldn't be the case.

When I complete the same steps at the Git command line I get the behaviour I expect i.e. the abandon/stash/commit alert halts the switch to the new branch and have to complete one of those steps and their is not bleeding between branches.

The command line behaviour is the one I expect and makes sense to be. Could someone tell me if my experience is correct with Egit or should it be like the command line?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your test was accurate. The command line will also switch without an error as long as - and that's the important point here - the switch wouldn't overwrite any of the uncommitted changes in the working directory.

Furthermore, your terminology is off:
You don't make changes in a branch. You make changes in your working directory.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you we're 100% correct. My original assumption was wrong. Once I got my brain around the idea that the working directory has a one to many relationship with branches the fog started to clear.

Answer (score 0):

Uncommitted changes do not belong to *any* branch. Your mental model is wrong, there is no issue with the tools.